# ASP to PHP ... simplifying php code

Tags: php, asp-classic

i'm converting some asp coding to php, from what I've done in php is there a better way to simplify things so I'm not writing an extra line of coding?

asp

```
xFirstName = LCase(Replace(request.form("xFirstName"), "'", "''"))
xFirstName = UCase(Left(xFirstName,1))& Mid(xFirstName,2)
```

php

```
$xFirstName = strtolower(str_replace("'","''",$_POST["xFirstName"]));
$xFirstName = strtoupper(substr($xFirstName,0,1)).substr($xFirstName,1);
```

Comment: This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're wanting to to replace single quotes with double quotes and capitalize the first letter of the word, which you could do with:

```
ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("'","''", $_POST['xFirstName'])));
```

This will capitalize the first letter of each word that's passed in the $_POST variable, so if you only want the first word capitalized regardless of how many words are present in xFirstName, you should use `ucfirst()` instead of `ucwords()`.

Comment: You still need to `strtolower()` it before `ucwords()`, and in order to exactly match the orginal code you should use `ucfirst()`, since `ucwords()` takes word boundaries into account, which the OPs code does not.

Comment: You're right, I've edited to reflect your points.

Answer (score 1):

```
strtoupper(substr($xFirstName,0,1)).substr($xFirstName,1);
```

can be effectively replaced with just

```
ucfirst($xFirstName)
```

As for the first line, it's still required - to make the string all lowercase first. Although I'd make the str_replace the final operation, as it may increase length of the string somewhat. ) So it becomes something like...

```
$xFirstName = str_replace("'", "''", 
    ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['xFirstName']))
);
```

Comment: `Although I'd make the str_replace the final operation, as it may increase length of the string somewhat.` - Not a *bad* suggestion as such, but definitely falls under the umbrella of micro-optimisation.

Comment: If micro-optimisation won't stand in the way of readability, why ignore it? ) ucfirst + strtolower is a single idiom, escaping the quotation is another - for me, at least. )

Comment: Agreed, there is no good reason *not* to do it, but I hesitate to recommend that sort of thing to others in case it causes them to pour over thousands of lines of code making thousands of changes that gain them a total of 10ms. Like I say, it's not a *bad* suggestion and after your edit with the full one-liner I think you deserve this tasty +1

Comment: Ah, now I see your point. ) Of course, the difference would be negligible - doubt it'll make even 10ms. )) Thank you for your comments and your +1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be with names `Peter O'Hara` or `Peter Clayton-Moore` etc when using the function `ucwords` You will end up with `Peter O'hara` or `Peter Clayton-moore`.

Better solution is to write own function like this:

```
public function my_ucwords($name) {
    $name = ucwords(str_replace('\'', '\' ', str_replace('-', '- ', $name)));
    return str_replace('\' ', '\'', str_replace('- ', '-', $name));
}
```

And then continue with this:

```
$xFirstName = str_replace("'","''", my_ucwords(mb_strtolower($_POST["xFirstName"])));
```

You're welcome!